# Formatting a bibliography for a specific journal's requirements

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing

A journal has asked me to format my work so it conforms with their citation and bibliography guidelines - the problem is that their formatting guidelines are *really weird*, and they don't have a template.

Here's a summary of my predicament.

### In-Text Citations

Rather than the in-text citations coming out as

> Read (2006, pp. 194--5) or (Read, 2006, pp. 194-5)

they need to look like this:

> Read [2006: 194--5], [Read 2006: 194--5]

(Same applies for year only citations)

### Article Bibliography Entries

Rather than the bibliography entry for an article being:

> Beall, J. C., & Restall, G. (2000). Logical Pluralism. *Australasian Journal of Philosophy*, 78(4), 475--493.

It should be:

> Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2000. Logical Pluralism, *Australasian Journal of Philosophy* 78/4: 475--93.

### Book Bibliography Entries

Rather than the bibliography entry for a book being:

> Beall, J. C., & Restall, G. (2006). *Logical Pluralism*. Oxford: Clarendon Press.

It should be:

> Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2006. *Logical Pluralism*, Oxford: Clarendon Press.

### Bibliography Entries for Chapters in Edited Volumes

Rather than the bibliography entry for a chapter in an edited volume being:

> Read, S. (2006). Monism: The One True Logic. In D. Devidi & T. Kenyon (Eds.), *A Logical Approach to Philosophy: Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon* (pp. 193--209). Dordrecht: Springer.

It should be:

> Read, S. 2006. Monism: The One True Logic, in *A Logical Approach to Philosophy: Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon*, ed. David Devidi and Tim Kenyon, Dordrecht: Springer: 193–209.

Here's a MWE with details of what I have and what I need:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{Read2006,
    address = {Dordrecht},
    author = {Read, Stephen},
    booktitle = {A Logical Approach to Philosophy: Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon},
    editor = {Devidi, David and Kenyon, Tim},
    file = {:Users/James/Documents/St Andrews/Philosophy/MPhil/MPhil Thesis/Readings/Normativity/Monism The One True Logic Read.pdf:pdf},
    pages = {193--209},
    publisher = {Springer},
    title = {{Monism: The One True Logic}},
    url = {https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/{~}slr/MONISM.PDF},
    year = {2006}
}

    @article{Beall2000,
        author = {Beall, J. C. and Restall, Greg},
        doi = {10.1080/00048400012349751},
        file = {:Users/James/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Beall, Restall - 2000 - Logical Pluralism.pdf:pdf},
        journal = {Australasian Journal of Philosophy},
        number = {4},
        pages = {475--493},
        title = {{Logical Pluralism}},
        url = {https://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?journalCode=rajp20},
        volume = {78},
        year = {2000}
    }

@book{Beall2005,
    address = {Oxford},
    author = {Beall, J. C. and Restall, Greg},
    file = {:Users/James/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Beall, Restall - 2005 - Logical Pluralism.pdf:pdf},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    title = {{Logical Pluralism}},
    year = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}} %gets rid of issue numbers
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{chapter}} %gets rid of chapters
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1} %stops capitalisation
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}} %deitalicises volume numbers
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} %separates entries



\title{\vspace{-20mm}Test Document}
\date{\vspace{-20mm}}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\noindent I need to cite \citet{Read2006}, \citet{Beall2000}, and \citet{Beall2005}. The references come out as below in the usual way. I need a number of different things:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Rather than the in-text citations coming out as \citet[194--5]{Read2006} or \citep[194--5]{Read2006}, they need to look like this: Read [2006: 194--5], [Read 2006: 194--5]. (Same applies for year only citations). 

    The key differences are: (i) square brackets instead of round ones; (ii) the lack of comma after the author's name; (iii) the p. or pp. prefix for page numbers being replaced with a colon.

    \item The bibliography entries for articles should look like: 

    Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2000. Logical Pluralism, \textit{Australasian Journal of Philosophy} 78/4: 475--93.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors; (iii) comma after the article title instead of a full-stop; (iv) no comma after the journal name; (v) the issue is not in brackets, but instead follows the volume and a `/' (i.e. 78/4 vs 78(4)); and (vi) page numbers follow the volume and issue number and a colon, rather than a comma.

    \item The bibliography entries for books should look like:

    Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2006. \textit{Logical Pluralism}, Oxford: Clarendon Press.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors; (iii) comma after the book title instead of a full stop.

    \item  The bibliography entries for book chapters should look like: 

    Read, S. 2006. Monism: The One True Logic, in \textit{A Logical Approach to Philosophy: Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon}, ed. David Devidi and Tim Kenyon, Dordrecht: Springer: 193–209.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors and editors; (iii) comma after the chapter title instead of a full-stop; (iv) book title follows chapter title, instead of editors; (v) comma after the book title instead of a full-stop; (v) ed. instead of (Eds.); (vi) editors' full names instead of first name initials; (vii) City and publisher follow editors names (and a comma), instead of page numbers; (viii) page numbers follow the publisher and a colon, rather than a comma.
\end{enumerate}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If someone is able to help me out with this -- even if only part of it -- it'd be immensely appreciated!

Comment: This style seems to be sufficiently far away from APA style that you may want to think about basing it on one of the standard styles (e.g. `style=authoryear,`) instead of `style=apa,`. Is there anything specific about the APA style that you need to reproduce (e.g. its complex "et al." rules, the dots for 'missing' authors in the bibliography, ...)?

Comment: I'm not particularly wedded to the APA style - it's just what I've been using as a base and then making small adjustments to because it's closest to what (most) philosophy journals require. I'm open to using a different style if that would make things easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you read on, please check with the journal editor if they can accept LaTeX submissions using `biblatex` for the bibliography. `biblatex` requires a very different workflow than BibTeX both for producing the bibliography as well as for possible post-processing of the file in their typesetting system.

As I commented under the question, I think the style is sufficiently dissimilar to APA that it makes sense to ditch it and start from a different style. `biblatex-apa` was written specifically to implement APA style in all its glory (and gory details). Since APA style is quite complex, `biblatex-apa` needs to do quite some work and that sometimes comes at the cost of customisability (and indeed by design `biblatex-apa` doesn't need to be customisable since its job is to implement APA style and not something else). In the following I base the style upon `ext-authoryear` of my `biblatex-ext` bundle.

The modifications should be self-explanatory (or at least understandable if you look up the command in the `biblatex` or `biblatex-ext` manual).

```
\documentclass[12pt,american]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,
  articlein=false,
  dashed=false,
  doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}

% well this is annoying ...
% we insert \closingrevsdnamepunct *after* the given name
% to the the commas around the initials right
\newcommand*{\closingrevsdnamepunct}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
    or
    test \ifmorenames
    }
    {\revsdnamepunct}
    {}}
% but that means we need to redefine the whole name:family-given
\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\ifcapital
            {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
            {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
          \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot
          \closingrevsdnamepunct}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibcompletenamefamilygiven{%
       \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
       \ifdefvoid{#4}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}%
       \ifboolexpe{%
         test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
         and
         test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
         {}
         {\revsdnamepunct}%
       \ifdefvoid{#2}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
       \ifdefvoid{#3}
         {}
         {\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifboolexpe{%
         test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
         and
         test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
         {}
         {\closingrevsdnamepunct}}}}

\DeclareNameFormat{family-given:init}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:family-given}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given:init}

\DeclareFieldFormat{biblabeldate}{#1}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nameyeardelim}{\addperiod\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addperiod\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{#1\isdot}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addslash}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\mkcomprange{#1}}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{textcite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkcomprange{#1}}


\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}%separates entries

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  byeditor = {ed\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Read2006,
  author        = {Read, Stephen},
  title         = {Monism: The One True Logic},
  editor        = {Devidi, David and Kenyon, Tim},
  booktitle     = {A Logical Approach to Philosophy},
  booktsubtitle = {Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon},
  year          = {2006},
  pages         = {193--209},
  publisher     = {Springer},
  address       = {Dordrecht},
  url           = {https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~slr/MONISM.PDF},
}
@article{Beall2000,
  author  = {Beall, J. C. and Restall, Greg},
  title   = {Logical Pluralism},
  journal = {Australasian Journal of Philosophy},
  volume  = {78},
  number  = {4},
  doi     = {10.1080/00048400012349751},
  pages   = {475--493},
  year    = {2000},
  url     = {https://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?journalCode=rajp20},
}
@book{Beall2005,
  author    = {Beall, J. C. and Restall, Greg},
  title     = {Logical Pluralism},
  year      = {2006},
  publisher = {Clarendon Press},
  address   = {Oxford},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent I need to cite \textcite{Read2006,Beall2000,Beall2005}. The references come out as below in the usual way. I need a number of different things:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Rather than the in-text citations coming out as \textcite[194-195]{Read2006} or \parencite[194--5]{Read2006}, they need to look like this: Read [2006: 194--5], [Read 2006: 194--5]. (Same applies for year only citations). 

    The key differences are: (i) square brackets instead of round ones; (ii) the lack of comma after the author's name; (iii) the p. or pp. prefix for page numbers being replaced with a colon.

    \item The bibliography entries for articles should look like: 

    Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2000. Logical Pluralism, \textit{Australasian Journal of Philosophy} 78/4: 475--93.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors; (iii) comma after the article title instead of a full-stop; (iv) no comma after the journal name; (v) the issue is not in brackets, but instead follows the volume and a `/' (i.e. 78/4 vs 78(4)); and (vi) page numbers follow the volume and issue number and a colon, rather than a comma.

    \item The bibliography entries for books should look like:

    Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2006. \textit{Logical Pluralism}, Oxford: Clarendon Press.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors; (iii) comma after the book title instead of a full stop.

    \item  The bibliography entries for book chapters should look like: 

    Read, S. 2006. Monism: The One True Logic, in \textit{A Logical Approach to Philosophy: Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon}, ed. David Devidi and Tim Kenyon, Dordrecht: Springer: 193–209.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors and editors; (iii) comma after the chapter title instead of a full-stop; (iv) book title follows chapter title, instead of editors; (v) comma after the book title instead of a full-stop; (v) ed. instead of (Eds.); (vi) editors' full names instead of first name initials; (vii) City and publisher follow editors names (and a comma), instead of page numbers; (viii) page numbers follow the publisher and a colon, rather than a comma.
\end{enumerate}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2000. Logical Pluralism, Australasian Journal of Philosophy 78/4: 475–93.//Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2006. Logical Pluralism, Oxford: Clarendon Press.//Read, S. 2006. Monism: The One True Logic, in A Logical Approach to Philosophy, ed. David Devidi and Tim Kenyon, Dordrecht: Springer: 193–209.]

Comment: Thanks so much for the time and effort you've put into this. Before I accept your answer, I'm having a couple of problems. When I copy and paste your code into texstudio, it says it can't fine the .bib file; but when I manually enter the file address the log says there's been an error (Undefined control sequence) on the line where the \end{document} command is, and warns that the .bib file if being overwritten. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @JamesSkinner The code as posted compiles fine for me. Can you upload the `.log` and `.blg` file you get when you try to compile the MWE to a text-sharing website such as https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Done - the file's title is Moewe. My computer doesn't have an application to open the .blg file, so it's just the .log file

Comment: @JamesSkinner Despite what your system may tell you, the `.blg` file is a simple text file that can be opened with any text editor. I found https://pastebin.com/WGKngshc on pastebin. Is that your `.log` file? In the future it would be much easier if you could link the file directly, so we don't have to rely on the search function (I didn't even realise pastebin had such a search ...). The `.log` shows that you get errors since some of the commands I use in my answer are undefined. That's because your system is outdated. Make an update and try again.

Comment: I've updated TexStudio but getting the same result. I'm not sure how to link files directly in pastebin - when I drag and drop the files the website stops working (sorry, I'm not the most techy person!). In the meantime, I've pasted both the .blg and .log files (named Moewe .blg and Moewe .log, respectively). Again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @JamesSkinner It's not TeXstudio you should be updating. You need to update TeX live (or MacTeX): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104704/discussion-between-james-skinner-and-moewe).

Answer (score 1):

- To replace "&" with "and":

  ```
  \DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}
  ```
- to get square brackets:

  ```
  \renewcommand{\bibrightparen}{]}
  \renewcommand{\bibleftparen}{[}
  ```
- no brackets in bibliography

  ```
  \AtBeginBibliography{
  \renewcommand{\bibrightparen}{}
  \renewcommand{\bibleftparen}{}
  }
  ```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{Read2006,
    address = {Dordrecht},
    author = {Read, Stephen},
    booktitle = {A Logical Approach to Philosophy: Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon},
    editor = {Devidi, David and Kenyon, Tim},
    file = {:Users/James/Documents/St Andrews/Philosophy/MPhil/MPhil Thesis/Readings/Normativity/Monism The One True Logic Read.pdf:pdf},
    pages = {193--209},
    publisher = {Springer},
    title = {{Monism: The One True Logic}},
    url = {https://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/{~}slr/MONISM.PDF},
    year = {2006}
}

    @article{Beall2000,
        author = {Beall, J. C. and Restall, Greg},
        doi = {10.1080/00048400012349751},
        file = {:Users/James/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Beall, Restall - 2000 - Logical Pluralism.pdf:pdf},
        journal = {Australasian Journal of Philosophy},
        number = {4},
        pages = {475--493},
        title = {{Logical Pluralism}},
        url = {https://www.tandfonline.com/action/journalInformation?journalCode=rajp20},
        volume = {78},
        year = {2000}
    }

@book{Beall2005,
    address = {Oxford},
    author = {Beall, J. C. and Restall, Greg},
    file = {:Users/James/Library/Application Support/Mendeley Desktop/Downloaded/Beall, Restall - 2005 - Logical Pluralism.pdf:pdf},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
    title = {{Logical Pluralism}},
    year = {2006}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa, natbib=true, doi=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{number}} %gets rid of issue numbers
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{chapter}} %gets rid of chapters
\DeclareFieldFormat{apacase}{#1} %stops capitalisation
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\apanum{#1}} %deitalicises volume numbers
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep} %separates entries



\DeclareDelimFormat*{finalnamedelim:apa:family-given}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\renewcommand{\bibrightparen}{]}
\renewcommand{\bibleftparen}{[}

\AtBeginBibliography{
\renewcommand{\bibrightparen}{}
\renewcommand{\bibleftparen}{}
}


\title{\vspace{-20mm}Test Document}
\date{\vspace{-20mm}}

\begin{document}


\maketitle

\noindent I need to cite \citet{Read2006}, \citet{Beall2000}, and \citet{Beall2005}. The references come out as below in the usual way. I need a number of different things:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Rather than the in-text citations coming out as \citet[194--5]{Read2006} or \citep[194--5]{Read2006}, they need to look like this: Read [2006: 194--5], [Read 2006: 194--5]. (Same applies for year only citations). 

    The key differences are: (i) square brackets instead of round ones; (ii) the lack of comma after the author's name; (iii) the p. or pp. prefix for page numbers being replaced with a colon.

    \item The bibliography entries for articles should look like: 

    Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2000. Logical Pluralism, \textit{Australasian Journal of Philosophy} 78/4: 475--93.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors; (iii) comma after the article title instead of a full-stop; (iv) no comma after the journal name; (v) the issue is not in brackets, but instead follows the volume and a `/' (i.e. 78/4 vs 78(4)); and (vi) page numbers follow the volume and issue number and a colon, rather than a comma.

    \item The bibliography entries for books should look like:

    Beall, J. C., and Restall, G. 2006. \textit{Logical Pluralism}, Oxford: Clarendon Press.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors; (iii) comma after the book title instead of a full stop.

    \item  The bibliography entries for book chapters should look like: 

    Read, S. 2006. Monism: The One True Logic, in \textit{A Logical Approach to Philosophy: Essays in Honour of Graham Solomon}, ed. David Devidi and Tim Kenyon, Dordrecht: Springer: 193–209.

    The key differences are: (i) no brackets around the year; (ii) use `and' instead of \& between authors and editors; (iii) comma after the chapter title instead of a full-stop; (iv) book title follows chapter title, instead of editors; (v) comma after the book title instead of a full-stop; (v) ed. instead of (Eds.); (vi) editors' full names instead of first name initials; (vii) City and publisher follow editors names (and a comma), instead of page numbers; (viii) page numbers follow the publisher and a colon, rather than a comma.
\end{enumerate}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Kate, thanks so much for this - super-helpful! Do you know how to make some of the other adjustments (e.g. commas between parts of references in the bibliography, colons instead of pp. and p. for in-text citations, etc)?